# Initializing data for a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a little new to MVC, so I need a little help with this.

I have this partial view:

```
@model MySite.Models.Account.UserProfile

<ul id="nav-user">
    <li class="user-name">
        @String.Format("{0} {1}", Model.FirstName, Model.LastName)
    </li>
</ul>
```

and rendering it in my Layout file:

```
<nav id="main">
    @Html.Partial("NavUserPartial")
</nav>
```

In WebForms, I would use a User Control named NavUser here, and set the logged-in data in the code behind of the user control.

How can I do that using a Partial View in MVC? Where do I set that data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the main view, create a viewmodel class.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

and use it in the partial view like so:

```
@model UserProfile 

<ul id="nav-user">
    <li class="user-name">
        @String.Format("{0} {1}", Model.FirstName, Model.LastName)
    </li>
</ul>
```

When rendering the main view, you can pass whatever you need like so:

```
<nav id="main">
    @Html.Partial("NavUserPartial", Model.UserProfile )
</nav>
```

Simply tailor the code to your needs.

I use viewmodels a lot, and overall they make designing MVC views a lot easier. Certainly my views are a lot easier to maintain.